# Lock Multi Transaction Asynch Database (Mongo Db) Calls

Tags: c#, multithreading, mongodb, asynchronous, locking

I have a mongo (offline) database call that deletes old records and then inserts new records from a SQL (online) database. I want to lock this method down to prevent race conditions such as below:

1. Thread 1 deletes old data
2. Thread 2 deletes (same) old data (which really doesn't exist anymore since thread 1 already took care of it)
3. Thread 1 inserts new data
4. Thread 2 inserts (same) new data; UNIQUE KEY VIOLATION WILL HAPPEN HERE!!!

I know a way to lock it down is to turn all the async methods in to sync methods by using the Task.Wait() or Task.Result, and then lock it down using c# lock method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx). But is that a good practice?

I was trying to follow Stephen Cleary's best practices on Asynch programming (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/JJ991977.aspx) and wanted to let the async calls bubble up so that would go against my suggested solution above of turning async methods back in to sync methods in attempt to be able to wrap it in the lock statement.

Here is the code sample:

```
    public async static Task SyncUserPermissionsForDocsAsync(List<long> docIdList)
    {
        var permissionListToSync = await OnlineDataAccess.GetPermissionListToSync(docIdList).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await OfflineDataAccess.DropUserPermissionAsync(docIdList).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await OfflineDataAccess.AddUserPermissionsAsync(permissionListToSync).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Comment: You probably should be using updates with upserts by the general look of things. That makes operations a lot more atomic in themselves without needing to artificially lock.

Comment: I actually need to delete old entries that may not have inserts so update would not work.

Comment: Well maybe so but what you presently have does not work. The general advice here is forget how you think it can be solved and just explain the full process and requirement. Personally a "synchronize" would be "update" and with timestamp, then drop of anything that did not update with that particular timestamp/flag. Avoids dropping everything first and any conflict there.

Comment: @BlakesSeven This is for an offline app that takes a filtered snapshot of what is online before it goes in to offline mode. I use mongo db as the offline storage to take snapshot of an online database (mssql). In the cases where new entries are added or updated in the online database, your suggestion of using an upsert to the offline db would work. But if any entries were deleted from the online database, the upsert would just ignore those and the deleted records would remain in the offline db. That's why I need to do a filtered delete of the old entries before inserting the records.

Comment: Then just delete anything that did not get updated at the last syncronize mark. I'm saying to also "mark" each record with that data as the upsert/updates occur. If the mark is not updated to the latest sync point then finally delete all data without that mark. So it's a bulk updates batch with all the upsert tagged operations with the final batch entry to delete anything ( and presumably also matched by user or similar ) that does not have the last tag as would be updated by all the changes. I'd basically answer that way but it's a simple principle you've missed both time I described already